# Помощь новичку Playground

Tags: swift, swift4, playground

Всем привет. Только приступил к изучению программирования , до этого вообще ни на чем ( наверное кроме бейсик в школе ) не программировал. Столкнулся с тупиком который не могу обойти.

Условия - имеется несколько человек , имен. Имеется общий счет ( допустим в баре ). Этот счет нужно распределить равномерно по нескольким людям в порядке убывания Имени - Уменьшается счет. Пока без сложностей сделал для 3х человек.

1.Как сделать так чтобы числа вставали напротив текста ? 
Если пишу в конце (sum) , выводится [Int,Int,Int] - http://joxi.ru/Q2Klxa7i98aRkA
или так : http://joxi.ru/82Q07x5i1GbqWm

2.Как можно сделать для разного количества человек ?
Те если добавить в nameOfFriends - "String" , появится sum4 и счет уменьшиться еще на 1/8 и тд.

```
let billOfDrinks = 1752

let nameOfFriends = ["Михаил","Александр", "Сергей"]

var sortedOfNames = nameOfFriends.sorted {
    (num1: String, num2: String)-> Bool in
    return num1 < num2
}

let sum1 = billOfDrinks * 1/2
let sum2 = billOfDrinks * 1/4
let sum3 = billOfDrinks * 1/6

let sum = [sum1,sum2,sum3]
var billForOne = sum.sorted {
    (num1: Int, num2: Int) -> Bool in
    return num1 > num2
}

for (names) in sortedOfNames {
    print ("\(names) должен заплатить ")
}
for (sum) in billForOne {
    print ("\(sum)")
}
```

Comment: Для начала объясните алгоритм распределения счета, т.к. 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/6 = 11/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итого получилось :

```
let billOfDrinks = 1752

let nameOfFriends = ["Михаил","Александр", "Сергей","Лариса","Михаил"]
var sortedOfNames = nameOfFriends.sorted {
(num1: String, num2: String)-> Bool in
return num1 < num2
}
var countOfFriends = nameOfFriends.count

var sum = [Int]()
var number = 2
for _ in 1...countOfFriends {
sum.append(billOfDrinks * 1/number)
number += 2    
}

var billForOne = sum.sorted {
(num1: Int, num2: Int) -> Bool in
return num1 > num2
}

for (index, names) in sortedOfNames.enumerated() {
print ("\(names) должен заплатить \(billForOne[index])") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так сделать

```
for (index, name) in sortedOfNames.enumerated() {
     print ("\(name) должен заплатить \(billForOne[index])")
}
```